# Search for "ilike" does not work after converting bytea to a text field in PostgreSQL ver.12 (for Cyrillic)

Tags: postgresql

We have a byte field that we save data to using the convert_to function. To extract data, use convert_from, respectively. But we got some problems with Cyrillic in PG12. Example:

```
select convert_from(convert_to('Берёза', 'UTF8'), 'UTF8') ilike 'берёз%' --return false
```

But everything works well with the Latin. Example:

```
select convert_from(convert_to('PostgreSQL', 'UTF8'), 'UTF8') ilike 'postgre%' --return true
```

The problem appeared in version 12, it can be seen, for example, on this resource https://dbfiddle.uk/ by selecting the appropriate version PG in the menu.
Can anyone help sort out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the result of `convert_from` is in the `C` collation:

On my system, I have the following:

```
SHOW lc_collate;

 lc_collate 
════════════
 de_AT.utf8
(1 row)

SELECT pg_collation_for('Берёза');

 pg_collation_for 
══════════════════
 (null)
(1 row)
```

The NULL value means that the default collation (`lc_collate`) will be used for comparisons:

```
SELECT 'Берёза' ilike 'берёз%';

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)
```

Now if we use `convert_from`, the collation is different, so the comparison is different:

```
SELECT pg_collation_for(convert_from(convert_to('Берёза', 'UTF8'), 'UTF8'));

 pg_collation_for 
══════════════════
 "C"
(1 row)

select convert_from(convert_to('Берёза', 'UTF8'), 'UTF8') ilike 'берёз%';

 ?column? 
══════════
 f
(1 row)

SELECT 'Берёза' COLLATE "C" ilike 'берёз%';
 ?column? 
══════════
 f
(1 row)
```

So you can solve the problem by explicitly specifying the default collation:

```
select convert_from(convert_to('Берёза', 'UTF8'), 'UTF8') COLLATE "default" ilike 'берёз%';

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: If you knew how much you helped us out, thank you! It works.